# Trigonometric substitution integral (How should I choose)

Tags: calculus, integration

For example,

$$\int \sqrt{1-4x^2}dx$$

How would I know that I should let $x=\sin \theta$ or $x=\frac{\sin \theta}{2}$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems the latter substitution makes more  sense, since the square root directly simplifies to $\cos \theta$,whereas in the other case you would get $\sqrt{1-4\sin^2 \theta}$, which doesn't look easy to simplify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" is the integrand has the $4x^2$ instead of just an $x^2$.  So, shuffle out the 4 by factoring:
$$
\sqrt{1-4x^2} = \sqrt{4\left(\frac{1}{4}-x^2\right)} =2 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2}.
$$
Now you have the "right" form $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ in which you are to substitute $x=a\sin \theta$.  Just don't forget that you have an extra constant $2$ out front due to the initial factoring trick.  How's that?

Comment: This is really helpful/ Thanks a lot

Comment: Yep, no problem.  The same thing works to put integrals like $\int \frac{1}{4+9x^2} \ dx$ in the "standard" form to be an arctangent without a lot of fuss.